# Condition for detection of collision in an algorithmic problem

Tags: algorithms, decision-problem, search-problem, square-grid

While solving [This](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc243/tasks/abc243_c) algorithm problem I was unable to come up with condition for the collision to occur ( other than the naive O(n^2) algorithm ) on reading the [explanation](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc243/editorial/3558)  they say

> Let’s deepen the observation. For a set of people with the same y coordinate, let’s consider “in what condition does a collision occurs?” Then we can see that a collision occurs if and only if the following two people collides:
> the leftmost person facing right, and
> the rightmost person facing left.
> In other words, among the people with the same y coordinate, all the people except for the two mentioned above is unimportant.

I am unable to understand how the two people who are at extremes of some `y=k` satisfy the condition it is quite possible that the two at extremes of this `y=k` face the same direction and there could exist some pair in between these extremes that satisfy the condition, can you help me understand if I'm wrong in understanding the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concern is legitimate.

However,

- "the leftmost person facing right" means the leftmost person among all persons who face right.
- "the rightmost person facing left" means the rightmost person among all persons who face left.

Comment: Yes I came to realize that and it worked, thanks for the clarification.